# JS code to move link location in custom policy doesn't work in azure b2c

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have to move my forgot password link, I used all steps for enabling javascript in my signin&signup custom policy like explained in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

My JS code is (it works in local html page not in azure) :

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-preload="true">
window.onload = function moveLinks() {

        alert("Test!!");
        /* Password Link*/
        v_div = document.createElement("div");
        v_div.setAttribute("id","divPass");
        
        
        var passLink = document.getElementById("forgotPassword");
        
        v_div.appendChild(passLink);
        next.parentNode.insertBefore(v_div, next.nextSibling);
}
</script>
```

when I inspect the page I see my js code in the head, no error is detected, the alert does not appear and I do not understand where the error comes from!!

Can someone help please?

Comment: Try `$(document).ready` instead of `window.onload`.

Comment: It still doesn't work.

Comment: I also tried window.addEventListener('load', moveLinks, false), an alert before and after appear but doesn't excute the function. I removed the preload='true' and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   The error is coming because your syntax is invalid because it seems you are trying to use an inline  tag as a javascript element since it is throwing an unexpected token error but  tags don’t work the same way they work in HTML as they still must follow javascript syntax, so they can’t contain arbitrary javascript code since you are modifying B2C page layout in custom policy code.

Thus, I would suggest you omit the  tag and do the following. Below is just a sample reference: -

```
  ‘ import {javascript} from ‘<name of the referencing HTML file>’;
   window.onload = function moveLinks() {

    alert("Test!!");
    /* Password Link*/
    v_div = document.createElement("div");
    v_div.setAttribute("id","divPass");
    
    
    var passLink = document.getElementById("forgotPassword");
    
    v_div.appendChild(passLink);
    next.parentNode.insertBefore(v_div, next.nextSibling);
   }
 export passLink;
```

Hence, by using the ‘import’ parameter, the javascript code can be rectified successfully. Also, please refer to the links below for more clarity on the code modification and compilation: -

https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/10628

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000IKXYQA4

Also, please refer to the link below for more details on customizing the B2C UI: -

https://moviesdiag132.blob.core.windows.net/b2c/global.css

Comment: Link https://moviesdiag132.blob.core.windows.net/b2c/global.css is broken